# Is anyone else having difficulty with Facebook SDK?

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, facebook-sdk-4.0

Because of the current bug where the latest version of Flutter can't build to the latest version of iOS (at least for some people), I upgraded my iOS, xcode, and mac to beta versions (and Catalina on mac). After doing this my project finally built and I was good for about 6 hours. When I got home from work I tried rebuilding my project and have been getting this error for about 14 hours, no matter how many fixes I try:

```
Module FBSDKCoreKit not found
```

I checked the Flutter docs and the current version of flutter_facebook_login says that the build status is failing. Do we just have to wait for a fix or is there a work around?
Project info:
Xcode - 11.4
Pubspec.yaml:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.5+2
  flutter_auth_buttons: ^0.5.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.3
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  json_serializable: ^2.2.1
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  smooth_star_rating: ^1.0.4+2
  #geolocator: ^3.0.1
  qr_flutter: ^2.0.0
  qr: ^1.2.0
  firebase_core: ^0.4.4+2
  dotted_border: ^1.0.4
  cached_network_image: ^2.0.0
  firebase_storage: ^3.1.1
  flutter_cache_manager: ^1.1.3
  camera: ^0.5.7+4
  image_picker: ^0.6.3+4
  path_provider: ^1.6.1
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out flutter_facebook_login is being deprecated. No more facebook sdk for flutter as of yet. Oof